# SwiftUI how to change color of a basic Text object

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui

For SwiftUI

`.fontColor`... no longer works.

Any thoughts on how to change the color of the text(not the background)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try:

```
Text("example").foregroundColor(.red)
```